# unable to requests.get() a website, 'Remote end closed connection without response'

Tags: python, web-scraping

when I try to send a request to this website:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://www.ldoceonline.com/')
```

An exception returned

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

The weird part is, if you access the website through normal approach(via a browser), they are fully functional and respond very well.  Only when you try to retrieve information via web-scraping technique do you encounter this response.

Any idea on how to successfully scraping it?

Answer (score 21):

Try using a header to get the desired response.

```
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.ldoceonline.com/',headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
print(res.status_code)
```

Output:

```
200
```

Comment: Can you please explain why the header resolves the issue?

Comment: Give [this link](https://dev.to/hhsm95/using-user-agent-to-scraping-data-lli) a go for clarity.

Answer (score 12):

If you inspect requests module's [code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests), you will find values of the [default headers](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/utils.py#L802) used while making a request. The above-mentioned [User-Agent](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/utils.py#L793) header is there too.

Seems like a bunch of webresources (whether intentionally or unintentionally) do not process requests properly if the User-Agent header is set to "python-requests/2.21.0".

So the practical solution is to use custom User-Agent header. User-Agent strings for different browsers are provided [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.ldoceonline.com/'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"}

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
r.raise_for_status()
```