# How to fix "Python requests.get(URL)'s Error"

Tags: python, pip, python-requests-html

I have a project that made dictionary related to mathmatical term so I am going to extract information from 'https://www.kms.or.kr' so I made code as below

```
import requests
URL = 'https://www.kms.or.kr'
response = requests.get(URL)
print(response)
```

But terminal says error like

```
$ C:/Users/HTER/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe "c:/Users/HTER/Desktop/1학년 여름방학 갓생살기 프로젝트/python/dictionary.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HTER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HTER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HTER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 454, in getresponse
    httplib_response = super().getresponse()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1378, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 287, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response   

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HTER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HTER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HTER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 470, in increment
    raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HTER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\util\util.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\HTER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HTER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HTER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 454, in getresponse
    httplib_response = super().getresponse()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1378, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 287, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\-----------------\python\dictionary.py", line 3, in <module>
    response = requests.get(URL)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\-----------------\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\-----------------\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\-----------------\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\-----------------\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\-----------------\requests\adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

IDK what to do..

It works when URL is Google like

```
URL = https://www.google.com/
```

Comment: You are missing headers to authenticate yourself as a User.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to requests.get() a website, 'Remote end closed connection without response'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597923/unable-to-requests-get-a-website-remote-end-closed-connection-without-respon)